# React Native OkHttpUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. In react-native-ssl-pinning

Tags: android, react-native, okhttp

Thanks in advance.
When I try to make the build for android using React native, Iam getting a build issue.

Any helps will be appreciated

This happens on android. But I didnt tried ios.

```
ReactNative\sslpin\node_modules\react-native-ssl-pinning\android\src\main\java\com\toyberman\RNSslPinn            ingModule.java:221: error: cannot find symbol
    @NonNull
     ^
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class RNSslPinningModule
Note: D:\Users\Ankit\Work\ReactNative\sslpin\node_modules\react-native-ssl-pinning\android\src\main\java\com\toyberman\Uti            ls\OkHttpUtils.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-ssl-pinning:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

It should provide me a build with this package.

Comment: do you recall if you have specified any version for okhttp? Also could you update question with `react-native` version, `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle`?

Comment: @ShocKwav3_ thanks for reply.
I uSe latest version of React: 60

do you recall if you have specified any version for okhttp? 
Didnt used any specific